# Simple counting with a small delay [lua, LÖVE]

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm brand new to lua and LÖVE.

I am trying to do a simple counting of numbers with a small delay, so that the user can see the count happen (instead of the code simply counting and then displaying the finished count)

I have the following code:

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print("Welcome again to a simple counting sheep excercise.", 50, 50)

    i = 20
    ypos = 70

    while i > 0 do

        love.graphics.print("Number: " .. i .. ".", 50, ypos)
        love.timer.sleep(1)
        i = i - 1
        ypos = ypos + 12


    end

end
```

But when I run it, it just hangs for ~20 seconds and then displays the completed count.  How do I make it pause briefly between each iteration?   I suspect that the problem is that the draw function is called once, and so it completes all of its work before displaying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`love.draw()` is called many times per second, so you shouldn't really sleep, because it causes the entire application to hang.

Instead, use `love.update()` to update the state of the application based on the current time (or based on time delta).

For example, I would express what you're trying to do as follows:

```
function love.load()
   initTime = love.timer.getTime()
   displayString = true
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print("Welcome again to a simple counting sheep excercise.", 50, 50)
    if displayString then
        love.graphics.print("Number: " .. currentNumber .. ".", 50, currentYpos)
    end
end

function love.update()
    local currentTime = love.timer.getTime()
    local timeDelta = math.floor(currentTime - initTime)
    currentNumber = 20 - timeDelta
    currentYpos = 70 + 12 * timeDelta
    if currentNumber < 0 then
        displayString = false
    end
end
```

First I find the initial time, and then I calculate the number and the position based on the time difference from the initial time. The difference is in seconds, which is why I call `math.floor` to make sure I get an integer.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it: update changes state, draw shows visual things depending upon that state.